# Compare a string with many values

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to add the below condition with java in Ireport:

```
Field.equals("red" or "bleu" or "black" or "....") ? "yes" : "no"
```

Do I have to use

```
Field.equals("..")||$F{color}.equals("..")
```

I have a long list.
Is there any other way to express it?

Answer (score 5):

Approach #1:

```
private static final HashSet<String> colors = new HashSet<>(
    Arrays.asList("red", "blue", "black", "sky-blue pink"));

res = (colors.contains(field)) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Approach #2 (Java 7 and later)

```
switch (field) {
case "red": case "blue": case "black": case "sky-blue pink": 
    res = "yes";
    break;
default:
    res = "no";
}
```

Approach #3 (Java 12 or later)

```
res = switch (field) {
    case "red", "blue", "black", "sky-blue pink" -> "yes";
    default -> "no";
};
```

---

The performance of the three approaches should be about the same.  Under the hood, string switch statements and switch expressions will *typically* use the equivalent of a static `HashMap` to map from the `field` value to either a value or a jump address.  However, if performance really matters to you, benchmark the alternatives *in the context of your application* (after profiling, etc).

To my mind, the last approach is the neatest ... if you have the freedom to use Java 12+.  The first approach has the possible advantage that the list of strings doesn't need to be hard-wired into your codebase.

Answer (score 2):

Keep a list of all the strings that you want to compare `Field` against

```java
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("red","blue","green");
return list.contains(field) ? "yes" : "no";
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String field = "brown";
        switch(field) {
            case "blue":
            case "black":
            case "red":
            case "yellow":
               System.out.println("Color :"+field);
            break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Not found");

        }
    }
}
```